# Grouping Similar words in python

Tags: python-3.x, text, nlp, cluster-analysis, spacy

I'm trying to extract keywords/entity names from a text using spacy.

I'm able to extract all the entity names but I'm getting a lot of duplicates.

For example,

```
def keywords(text): 
    tags = bla_bla(text)
    return tags
article = "Donald Trump. Trump. Trump. Donald. Donald J Trump."
tags = keywords(article)
```

The output I'm getting is:
['Donald Trump', 'Trump', 'Trump', 'Donald', 'Donald J Trump']

How do I cluster all these tags under a master tag 'Donald J Trump'?

Comment: use a dictionary `{'master_tag': [list-of-other-tags]}`

Comment: Is there any way to do this dynamically? I mean, Trump one is an example but I have a lot of other tags to group.

Answer (score 0):

1) Easy way: keep only the longest entities that contains smaller
2) More time consuming: make dictionaries of entities
3) ML: vectorize entities with bag of words and cluster them, the longest entity in cluster will be "main"

Answer (score 0):

With a carefully built dictionary.

There is no unsupervised/clustering that would do this reliably.

Consider the following sentence:

> President Trump met with his son, Donald Trump Jr.